# How to set up the font Scheherazade for use with XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, arabic

When compiling the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\begin{document}
ل    
\end{document}
```

using `xelatex` I obtain the error

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /usr/share/font/woff/scheherazade/Scheherazade-Regular.woff
```

Apparently the fonts are not part of TeXLive 2016, so I downloaded `Scheherazade-2.100.zip` from [SIL International](http://software.sil.org/scheherazade/download/), unpacked it into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype`, and ran `mktexlsr`. According to [Installing TeX fonts](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) I am now supposed to run `updmap` on a `.map` file, but there is none.

So my questions are:

- How does this `.map` look like, where do I get it from?
- Is there anything else missing for setting up the font correctly?

**Edit:** Apparently my Ubuntu installation already contained the Scheherazade fonts from installing the package `fonts-sil-scheherazade`, which puts them at `/usr/share/fonts/woff/scheherazade/`. When adding the link `/usr/share/font -> /usr/share/fonts` (there was no `font` before), `xelatex`/`xdvipdfmx` somehow takes notice since it corrects the path in the error message from `font` to `fonts`, but otherwise still the same.

Comment: You don't need map-files or updmap. It looks as if xetex is finding the wrong font. Try to use the filename: `{Scheherazade-Regular.ttf}`

Comment: I literally had the same problem @UlrikeFischer's solution is the way to fix it. The `.woff` version is a different version of the font that XeTeX can't really work with. P.S. as a bonus, I recommend scaling scheherazade as I find it's very small in its default size. Play around with `\newfontfamily{\AR}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.7]{Scheherazade-Regular.ttf}` and see if it suits your taste

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, this solved the problem!

Comment: You should uninstall the WOFF version of the fonts, these are meant for use on the web and XeTeX does not support them.

Answer (score 6):

You should uninstall the WOFF version of the fonts, these are meant for use on the web and XeTeX does not support them.

It seems that XeTeX (*the engine*) will happily process WOFF files since it uses FreeType to load the fonts and FreeType supports WOFF fonts, but dvipdfmx (*the output driver*) does not support them and will give the error you got (the wording is slightly misleading, it did find the font specified but it does not know how to process it).

Comment: This worked for me; I just deleted `/usr/share/fonts/woff`, although it would have been nice if I could configure XeTeX to just not look there. Thanks!

Comment: @goodmami: XeTeX uses FontConfig in Linux, you can blacklist certain font directories, though I’m not sure it can be done per-application. My suggestion would be to file a report against your Linux distribution, installing the same font in various formats system-wide is always a bad thing, not to mention that WOFF is intended for use om the Web,