# xelatex does not find Fira Sans using metropolis theme (beamer)

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex

I am using beamer with metropolis to make a presentation. I installed the Fira font family and everything seems to work (I can use it in other programs). However, everytime I try to compile my presentation, xelatex aborts with the error message:

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/FiraSans/Normal/Roman/FiraSans-Regular.woff
```

The font exists at this path and it is listed by fc-list, so it seems very cryptic to me. I think it is something specific to my texLive installation or the way I installed the Fira fonts, since it compiles on Windows (I am using Ubuntu). There is nothing special about the presentation, the following MWE reproduces this error:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usetheme[numbering=none,sectionpage=none,subsectionpage=none,block=fill]{metropolis}

\setsansfont[BoldFont={Fira Sans}]{Fira Sans Light}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}

\title{This is the title}
\subtitle{with subtitle}
\date{Feb 2018}
\author{author}
\institute{institution}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{the title}
    \begin{center}
        This is the text
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

UPDATE: adding relevant sections of mwe.log

```
\c@fontsnotfound=\count326
\g__fontspec_family_FiraSansLight_int=\count327
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'FiraSansLight(0)' created for font 'Fira Sans Light' with
. options [Ligatures=TeX,ItalicFont={Fira Sans Light Italic},BoldFont={Fira
. Sans},BoldItalicFont={Fira Sans Italic}].
.  
.  This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
.  
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans
. Light/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans
. Light/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Sans/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Sans/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans Light
. Italic/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans Light
. Italic/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans
. Italic/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans
. Italic/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
.................................................
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 95.

*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature"
* 
* Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'HyphenChar'.
*************************************************
\g__fontspec_family_FiraMono_int=\count328
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font "Fira Mono Medium/I" (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font "Fira Mono/I" (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature"
* 
* Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'HyphenChar'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature"
* 
* Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'HyphenChar'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature"
* 
* Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'HyphenChar'.
*************************************************
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'FiraMono(0)' created for font 'Fira Mono' with options
. [WordSpace={1,0,0},HyphenChar=None,PunctuationSpace=WordSpace,BoldFont={Fira
. Mono Medium}].
.  
.  This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
.  
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Mono/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
. \hyphenchar \font =-1\relax 
. - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Mono
. Medium/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
. \hyphenchar \font =-1\relax 
. - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Mono/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
. \hyphenchar \font =-1\relax 
.................................................
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 95.
))
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'FiraSansLight(1)' created for font 'Fira Sans Light' with
. options [Ligatures=TeX,BoldFont={Fira Sans}].
.  
.  This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
.  
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans
. Light/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans
. Light/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Sans/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Sans/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans
. Light/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira Sans
. Light/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Sans/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Sans/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
.................................................
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 6.

*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature"
* 
* Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'HyphenChar'.
*************************************************
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font "Fira Mono/I" (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature"
* 
* Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'HyphenChar'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature"
* 
* Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'HyphenChar'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature"
* 
* Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'HyphenChar'.
*************************************************
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'FiraMono(1)' created for font 'Fira Mono' with options
. [WordSpace={1,0,0},HyphenChar=None,PunctuationSpace=WordSpace].
.  
.  This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
.  
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Mono/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
. \hyphenchar \font =-1\relax 
. - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Mono/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
. \hyphenchar \font =-1\relax 
. - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
. Mono/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
. \hyphenchar \font =-1\relax 
.................................................
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 7.
(./mwe.aux)
\openout1 = `mwe.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 17.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: includehead includefoot 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(28.45274pt, 307.28987pt, 28.45274pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(0.0pt, 273.14662pt, 0.0pt)
* \paperwidth=364.19536pt
* \paperheight=273.14662pt
* \textwidth=307.28987pt
* \textheight=244.6939pt
* \oddsidemargin=-43.81725pt
* \evensidemargin=-43.81725pt
* \topmargin=-72.26999pt
* \headheight=14.22636pt
* \headsep=0.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=14.22636pt
* \marginparwidth=4.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box75
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 17.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count329
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 17.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 17.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 17.

(./mwe.out) (./mwe.out)
\@outlinefile=\write5
\openout5 = `mwe.out'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmss/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/cmss/bx/n on input line 17.
\symnumbers=\mathgroup6
\sympureletters=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/bx/n on input line
 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/bx/n on input line
 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathsf on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/m/n on input line 
17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/m/n on input line
 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/m/it on input line
 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/m/it on input lin
e 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathtt on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/FiraMono(1)/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/FiraMono(1)/m/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `numbers' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/FiraSansLight(1)/m/n --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/bx/n on
 input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `pureletters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/FiraSansLight(1)/m/it --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/bx/it 
on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/FiraSansLight(1)/bx/n --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/bx/n o
n input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/FiraSansLight(1)/m/n --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/bx/n on
 input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/FiraSansLight(1)/m/it --> TU/FiraSansLight(1)/bx/it 
on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/FiraMono(1)/m/n --> TU/FiraMono(1)/bx/n on input lin
e 17.
```

Comment: As a test: Does it work without the two lines `\setsansfont[BoldFont={Fira Sans}]{Fira Sans Light}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}`?

Comment: @samcater Without those lines, the same error occurs...

Comment: Can you please add the log file from your MWE?

Comment: .woff fonts shouldn't be in the search path. xelatex can't use them. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330195/2388 and https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/139/

Comment: @samcarter added the relevant sections of the log. the full log is too long

Comment: how do I tell xetex to use ttf (or some other format) instead of woff?

Comment: OK, explicitly adding the filename for the (ttf) font I want to use solves the problem. Explicitly, using FiraSans-Regular.ttf and so on when choosing the font works. Thanks to both samcarter and Ulrike Fischer!  Shall I post an answer?

Answer (score 7):

I am posting the answer here but it is mostly answered from [How to set up the font Scheherazade for use with XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330195/2388)

I simply replaced

```
\setsansfont[BoldFont={Fira Sans}]{Fira Sans Light}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
```

by

```
\setsansfont[BoldFont={FiraSans-Bold.ttf}]{FiraSans-Light.ttf}
\setmonofont{FiraMono-Regular.ttf}
```

to force xelatex to use those fonts instead of whatever it finds in the path that matches the name I provide.

Thanks to both [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) and [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [Fira Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Sans?preview.text_type=custom) and extracted the font `/usr/share/fonts` subfolder, as in :

```bash
 unzip Fira_Sans.zip -d /usr/share/fonts/truetype/Fira_Sans/
```